# Untracable glassfish docker container image or clean installation?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

For a customer I need to create a glassfish container, containing the glassfish 5.0 release.

I have been looking for standard glassfish images on docker hub, and other places, but can't manage to find a recent image containing a recent glassfish release. For some reason, I also can't find, glassfish isn't available on dockerhub anymore. Only thing I could find is a reference to glassfish server on dockerhub, but that's also gone for some unclear reason.

Now am I correct to just use a clean docker image and create a new one where I install glassfish myself?

Answer (score 1):

Look into Payara.  It's a Glassfish fork/drop-in replacement that's better in most ways, including support.

There is a Payara 5 docker image available right on docker hub:

https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/server-full